# Automatic Code Optimization Techniques

Tags: java, optimization, compilation, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am working on a project to automatically convert a custom language to Java and have been asked to do some basic optimizations of the code during the conversion process. For example, the custom code may have something like:

```
if someFunction(a, b) > x:
    do something
else:
    return someFunction(a, b) + y
```

in this instance, someFunction is called multiple times with the same inputs, so additional performance can be obtained by caching the value of someFunction() and only calling it once. Thus, an "optimized" version of the above code may look something like:

```
var1 = someFunction(a, b)

if var1 > x:
    do something
else:
    return var1 + y
```

Currently, this is done by hand during the conversion process. I run a program to convert the code in the custom language to Java and then manually examine the converted code to see what can be optimized. I want to automate the optimization process since these problems creep up again and again. The people who are writing the code in the custom language do not want to worry about such things, so I can't ask them to just make sure that the code they give me is already optimized.

What are some tutorials, papers, etc... that details how such things are done in modern compilers? I don't want to have to re-invent the wheel too much. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

It can be assumed that the function is pure.

Comment: This optimization will only work if you are guaranteed that `someFunction` will always return the same value for the same input; do you have guarantees of any kind about that?

Comment: You have to infer the fact that your function is pure (does not have side effects). How easy it is to do depends on your language. For a *mostly* functional language the purity inference is trivial, otherwise you can only have very conservative inference rules. The details also depend on your intermediate representation. If it is an SSA/ArraySSA (i.e., you have eliminated all the local-only memory transfers), you can mark a function as pure if it does not do any loads and stores and only calls the other pure functions.

Comment: It can be assumed that the function is pure.

Comment: There isn't any point in you doing optimizatinons that the Java compiler will do.   Do you actually know what optimizations it does?

Comment: In this case it's just a trivial common subexpression elimination.

Comment: If you don’t want to reinvent the wheel and are targeting Java as execution environment anyway, well, just let the JVM’s optimizer do the job.

Comment: more technics can be found here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#List_of_static_code_analyses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination).

Normally, this would require you pretty much implement a full compiler in order to do the data flow analysis. An algorithm is given in [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321486811), "6.1.2 The Value-Number Method for Constructing DAG's" (for the local CSE at least).

Comment: This isn't quite common subexpression elimination because the function call might have side effects and therefore it might not be possible to eliminate it.

Comment: He has stated the the functions he wants to evaluate are pure